# JQuery/Javascript Hide Menu SlideUp effect

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, function

I'm trying to implement a SlideDown/SlideUp type effect on my bootstrap navbar.

I have added a standard javascript function as seen below. But it doesn't seem to work and conflicts with the page-scroll function. Is it possible to fix this issue?

Code: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/VXGYBq

```
window.onscroll = function() {scrollFunction()};
function scrollFunction() {
if (document.body.scrollTop > 20 || document.documentElement.scrollTop > 20) {
document.getElementsByClassName("navbar").style.top = "0";
} else {
document.getElementsByClassName("navbar").style.top = "-50px";
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

replace
    document.getElementsByClassName("navbar") by document.querySelector(."navbar").......

so ur code should be like this:

```
window.onscroll = function() {scrollFunction()};
function scrollFunction() {
    if (document.body.scrollTop > 20 || document.documentElement.scrollTop > 20) {
document.querySelector(".navbar").style.top = "0";
} else {
document.querySelector(".navbar").style.top = "-50px";
  }
}
```

u can t type getElementsbyClassName because u just have one element.
so its better to do a querySelector for this kind of things

Answer (score 0):

```
window.onscroll = function() {scrollFunction()};
function scrollFunction() {
if (document.body.scrollTop > 20 || document.documentElement.scrollTop > 20) {
document.getElementsByClassName("navbar")[0].style.top = "0";
} else {
document.getElementsByClassName("navbar")[0].style.top = "-50px";
}
}
```

document.getElementsByClassName return all elements with this classs
you need to add [0] after it

Comment: Is it possible to have it completely hide when the user stops scrolling?

Comment: yes it's possible. Get the scrollTop in a variable and compare it with the actual scrollTop in a SetTimeout